# Spring boot Rest controller - convert form-encoded body to POJO

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, httprequest

I would like to process an HTTP POST request hitting my rest endpoint and convert its body to my defined POJO. I was successful in the past with mapping between JSON and POJOs but I am struggling with this form encoded content.

I have a controller as follows:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController("/example")
public class GatewayController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public void describeInstances(@RequestBody MyPojo body) {

        log.debug("Value1: " + body.getValue1());

    }

}
```

And a POJO:

```
@Data
public class MyPojo {

 private String value1;
 private String value2;
 ...
}
```

I am hitting the controller with a POST request which looks as follows:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: value1=abc&value2=efg...
```

But all I am getting is `415 Unsupported Media Type`. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: when I change the POJO into String and just print the body, it works (without receving the unsupported media type exception) so it is definitely in the POJO declaration.

**Follow up:**

Is it possible to annotate the POJO attributes to allow different names of the fields (to avoid using undorscope inside variable names, for example)?

Something like:

```
@Attribute("value_name")
private String valName;
```

Comment: Are you using Jackson for JSON-POJO binding ? Do you see any errors from Jackson like "no constructor to make MyPojo" ?

Comment: the data inside the request body are not JSON but form-encoded. So there is no need for jackson, right? I am not getting ANY exceptions other than 415...

Comment: You are of course correct, you don't need jackson for this. You may still need to define a default constructor though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ModelAttribute` is the recommended way to get form data in your controller. e.g.

```
public void describeInstances(@ModelAttribute("mypojo") MyPojo body)
```

and

```
@Data
@ModelAttribute("mypojo")
public class MyPojo {
```

Read the spring docs for more info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. As for my question - how about assigning custom names to the class properties? Is this possible but do the names have to match everytime?

Comment: I am not familiar with an easy way to do that. I actually think using the same names is good practice but that is just me.